# Slim is giving undefined error with middleman

Tags: ruby, slim-lang, middleman

Have tried searching for some blogs on resolving this issue, unable to do so.

Getting the following error when I try starting middleman server.

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.3.10/lib/middleman-core/renderers/slim.rb:31:in
`registered': undefined method `set_options' for 
Slim::Engine:Class (NoMethodError)`
```

Here's my Gemfile ->

```
gem "middleman", "~>3.3.10"
gem "slim", ">= 2.0"

# Live-reloading plugin
gem "middleman-livereload", "~> 3.1.0"

# for faster file watcher updates on windows:
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.0", :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]

# windows does not come with time zone data
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mswin, :mingw]
gem 'middleman-php', :git => 'https://github.com/appjudo/middleman-php.git', :branch => 'master'
gem 'skim'
```

[This](http://pastebin.com/KkAdsTcd) - is the gemlock file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after updating an old version of middleman to 3.4

I figured my Slim was old so I found the latest version by executing this at the command prompt:

```
gem list slim --remote
```

Then I updated my `gemfile` to include the newer version of slim like this:

```
gem "slim", "~> 3.0"
```

Then I did `bundle install` and `middleman` and the error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with my latest site I did `bundle update` and then `bundle exec middleman s` and somehow it ran fine.

Comment: bundle update 
# updated to: Installing slim 3.0.3 (was 2.1.0) does the trick